# Predict label of one single image using DeepLearnToolbox

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using [DeepLearnToolbox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox) to do CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks).

I have computed my network successfully and I've seen my accuracy, but my question is:

how can I query one single image into the network in order to get the label predicted?

The final result that I want to get is a label predicted, with maybe the error for each label not predicted.

Thank you.

---

This is the code that I have for testing the accuracy:

```
function [er, bad] = cnntest(net, x, y) % net = network, x = test_x (images), y = test_y (labels)
    %  feedforward
    net = cnnff(net, x);
    [~, h] = max(net.o);
    [~, a] = max(y);
    bad = find(h ~= a);

    er = numel(bad) / size(y, 2);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines

```
net = cnnff(net, x);
[~, h] = max(net.o);
```

feed an image `x` through the network and then compute the index `h` which had the largest output activation. You can simply do the same for an arbitrary input image `x` and it will give you the class `h`.

Comment: Have you ever tried this implementation ? what does `net.o` means ?? does it mean the *closeness* or *remoteness* of every label??? thank you very much

Comment: @RafaFirenze: I haven't worked with this toolbox. But `net.o` are simply the values of the neurons in the output layer, and there are as many as there are classes in your problem. By taking the neuron with the maximum value, you determine the most likely class predicted by your model.